# trying to add sums from a foreach, but only returns one value

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

Each instance of $surrender has multiple features, each with a different rarity
I want to calculate a total based on the combined

the following is my code

```
$features = $surrender->character->image->features()->get();
foreach($features as $traits) {
$rarity = Rarity::where('id', $traits->rarity_id)->first();

switch($rarity->name) {
// e.g if the rarity name returns rare, the cost is 100
case 'rare':
$cost = 100;
break;
}};

$totalcost = collect($cost)->sum();
}
else $totalcost = NULL;
```

However, this returns just 100 when for example I have two features of the rarity 'rare'.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfF6a.png)

How can I amend my code to function correctly?

Comment: You're just overwriting the `$cost` variable every loop, not adding to it. Please indent your code properly to improve readability.

Comment: @miken32 it was indented, but i removed it since it is usually removed from my questions. Where should I place $cost instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assiging the same value in every loop:

```
$cost = 100;
```

To get your summary, you could simply accumulate the costs:

```
$cost += 100;
```

Applying it to your snippet:

```
$features = $surrender->character->image->features()->get();
$totalCost = 0;

foreach ($features as $traits) {
    $rarity = Rarity::where('id', $traits->rarity_id)->first();

    switch ($rarity->name) {
        // e.g if the rarity name returns rare, the cost is 100
        case 'rare':
            $totalCost += 100;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Question already has a selected answer.

If anyone is interested in a refactored code, with laravel `collection` methods.

```php
$totalCost = $surrender->character->image->features->sum(function($feature) {
    return Rarity::where('id', $traits->rarity_id)->where('name', 'rare')->exists() ? 100 : 0;
});
```

**To be more efficient**

The issue with the previous approach is there is going to be multiple number of database calls for get the `rare` of each `feature`. To avoid that we can eager load `rare`.

Define `rarity()` relation in the `Feature` model

```php
public function rarity()
{
    return $this->bgelongsTo(Rarity::class);
}
```

Now in the Controller

```php
$features = $surrender->character->image->features()->with('rarity')->get();

$totalCost = $features->sum(function($feature) {
    return $feature->rarity->name == 'rare' ? 100 : 0;
});
```

**Another approach**

I assume you want to sum up the rarity of the 'rare features' only. Then lets fetch only the features which are rare.

```php
$rarefeatures = $surrender->character->image->features()
    ->whereHas('rarity', function($query) {
        return $query->name('name', 'rare');       
    })->get();

$totalCost = $rareFeatures->sum(function($feature) {
    return 100;
});
```

**Another approach**

Seems like we don't even want to fetch the 'rare features'. We just only need the count of the 'rare features'.

```php
$rareFeaturesCount = $surrender->character->image->features()
    ->whereHas('rarity', function($query) {
        return $query->name('name', 'rare');       
    })->count();

$totalCost = 100 * $rareFeaturesCount;
```

Comment: this is an extremely helpful comment, thank you so much for taking the time to answer, even though i had already selected an answer!